# uniformly distributing values from a list of strings

Tags: python, random, sample, uniform

in Python:
I have a list of 5 elements: 
list= ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'pig', None]
and i need to distribute them uniformly in a column of 200 rows, so that each row will have an animal that was chosen randomly. 
I have read that random doesn't choose values uniformly, but I need that the probability for each animal to appear in a specific row would be equal.
I thought about using sample.random.uniform but I'm not sure how to implement what I need...

Comment: `I have read that random doesn't choose values uniformly` well you read wrong. Anyways just use `random.choices(l, k=100)` where l is your list.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: it worked, thank you very much!!! :)